# React looping through API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, fetch-api

I'm fetching data from an API using react and displaying it in a bootstrap container. I'm trying to implement react map to iterate through every entry in the database.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Home.css";
import Icon from "./../Images/icon.png";
import Popup from "./Popup";

export default class GetFullName extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showPopup: false };
    }

    togglePopup() {
        this.setState({
            showPopup: !this.state.showPopup
        });
    }

    state = {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        fullName: null,
        jobRole: null,
        about: null,

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://localhost:44362/api/peopleprofiles";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ firstName: data[0].firstName })
        this.setState({ lastName: data[0].lastName })
        this.setState({ fullName: this.state.firstName + " " + this.state.lastName })
        this.setState({ jobRole: data[0].roleType.jobRole })
        this.setState({ about: data[0].about })
        this.setState({ image: window.btoa(data[0].iconNavigation.image) })
        this.setState({ image: "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, " + window.btoa(data[0].iconNavigation.image) + "" })
        console.log(data)
    }


    render() {
        return (
                <div className="container PeopleProfile">
                    <div className="row flex-grow">
                        <div className="col-2">
                        <img src={this.state.image} className="Icon" alt="ProfileIcon" />
                        //<img src={Icon} className="Icon" alt="ProfileIcon" />
                        </div>  
                        <div className="col-10">
                            <div className="row PeopleProfile">
                                <p id="ppName"><div>{this.state.fullName}</div></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row ppjobTitle">
                                <p id="ppjobTitle"><div>{this.state.jobRole}</div></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row PeopleProfile">
                            <p id="ppDescription"><div>{this.state.about}</div></p>
                            </div>
                                <div className="row PeopleProfile">
                                    <div className="ppButton">

                                <input type="submit" onClick={this.togglePopup.bind(this)} value="Full profile" id="PeopleProfileBTN" class="align-self-end btn btn-lg btn-block"></input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        {this.state.showPopup ?
                                        <Popup
                                            text='Click "Close Button" to hide popup'
                                            closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
                                            />
                                            : null
                                         }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }

}
```

This is my current code. I have tried to used react map but can't seem to get it working. Does anyone know how i can correctly implement react map into this project or a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move state value that are declared out side of the constructor inside the state object of the constructor.

```
    state = {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        fullName: null,
        jobRole: null,
        about: null,

    }
```

into constructor

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showPopup: false,
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            fullName: null,
            jobRole: null,
            about: null,
        };
    }
```

setState is an asynchronous function. Try making a single update.
Insted of this

```
 this.setState({ firstName: data[0].firstName })
        this.setState({ lastName: data[0].lastName })
        this.setState({ fullName: this.state.firstName + " " + this.state.lastName })
        this.setState({ jobRole: data[0].roleType.jobRole })
        this.setState({ about: data[0].about })
        this.setState({ image: window.btoa(data[0].iconNavigation.image) })
        this.setState({ image: "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, " + window.btoa(data[0].iconNavigation.image) + "" })
```

do this

```
this.setState({
            firstName: data[0].firstName,
            lastName: data[0].lastName,
            fullName: data[0].firstName + " " + data[0].lastName,
            jobRole: data[0].roleType.jobRole,
            about: data[0].about,
            image: window.btoa(data[0].iconNavigation.image),
            image: "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, " + window.btoa(data[0].iconNavigation.image) + ""
        });
```

There are 2 image property in the state, remove one of it.